# Elixir converting datetime to string

Tags: elixir, ecto, timex

I have a raw sql query which returns a datetime field and I want to return a json with those results.

If I put the return value I get a complain:

`(Poison.EncodeError) unable to encode value: {{2017, 3, 21}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}`

If I try to transform it to string using `Timex`:

`Timex.format!(Ecto.DateTime.from_erl(datetime_field), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", :strftime)`

I get:

`** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Ecto.DateTime.from_erl/1`

If I skip the `from_erl` part:

`Timex.format!(datetime_field, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", :strftime)`

I get:

`** (Poison.EncodeError) unable to encode value: {:error, :invalid_date}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To obtain a standard `erlang` datetime value need to remove fourth value (microseconds) from the second tuple:

```
datetime = {{2017, 3, 21}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}
{{year, month, day}, {hours, minutes, seconds, _}} = datetime
datetime = {{year, month, day}, {hours, minutes, seconds}}
Poison.encode! Ecto.DateTime.from_erl(datetime)
#=> "\"2017-03-21T00:00:00\""
```

Comment: wasn't going to find this anytime soon

Answer (score 2):

Per the Ecto 3.0 changelog, `Ecto.DateTime` no longer exists.  In the cases where you do not have timezone information available, you can use `NaiveDateTime.from_erl()` as a replacement for `Ecto.DateTime.from_erl()`

If you need more formatting beyond the basic iso8601 or to_string stuff, you'll want to look at https://hexdocs.pm/timex/Timex.html#format/2